# Hibernate loading associated entities not by primary key

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables (really simplified for the sake of the question):

```java
Book {
  id Integer,
  name String,
  author_id Integer
}

Author {
  id Integer,
  fullName String
}
```

Now I need to save the `Book`, but I don't have `author_id`, I just have author's `fullName`.

I can get the author by name, then do `book.set(thatAuthor)`, but I have more fields in many classes, I have to fill all those objects and it's more code than I would like for this, especially since I'm using map-struct to map everything and then I would just like to call persist and be done with it, but I can't, I have to set those fields manually.

Question: is there a possiblity to tell Hibernate to do it? I have the entity class filled with data (author's `fullName` is set) and it's unique so if Hibernate tried to do this he would only find 1 result, no problems there.

I have in mind such functionality: Hibernate looks at the class. It sees that some fields are set and some other are not. It takes all the fields that are set and puts them all in `where clause` (in my case it's only authors `fullName`) and tries to find a single result, throws Exception otherwise.

Not sure if you can understand me, tried my best. Don't hate me for the question, all I could find was to do what I did, loading the objects manually. If I can possibly avoid lots of code by asking this question - why not try?

Comment: No, Hibernate won't do it for you. Just execute the query to get the author by full name.

Comment: classes are not properly designed. Among others have very basic problem: unique Author's name, it is not artificial problem (I'm client of classic, paper library). I have no (big) problem with pseudo-code, but probably You see, it is not strict. Real entity class with, or without unique specification will be good.

Comment: Re "avoid lots of code" ... use tools with good patterns? Relational databases have 50 years, correct design Book-Author dilema is known since half of century. BTW I can give answer with correctly defined classes, but "good tradition"  in SO is downvote "not in subject"